# R: two functions with the same name and :: doesn't to work

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to use the **as.raster** function of the **raster** package, but there is already a function with the same name in the **grDevices** package. So, I use the :: operator to differentiate between the two, but it doesn't appear to work. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong? Minimal working example below:

```
library("raster")
a <- matrix(1:15, ncol=3)
raster::as.raster(a)
```

Output:

```
Error in rgb(tx, tx, tx, maxColorValue = max) : 
color intensity 6, not in [0,1]
```

This error message is for the **grDevices** version of the function.

Comment: Did you carefully read the help page of `raster::as.raster`? It is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. You are confusing `raster` and `Raster` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be trying to convert a variable of class `matrix` into a variable of class `RasterLayer`. The command `as.raster` when it receives a matrix, assumes you are using the grDevices-package version, since the raster-package version is designed to accept a `RasterLayer` object.

In your example, simply use `raster(a)`.